# Setting up Secured SSL, WCF using windows authentication

Tags: web-services, wcf, authentication, ssl

Ok, I really need help getting this setup.  Currently i have an ssl cert installed. I have a wcf service installed in iis as an application.  I have set it to require ssl and i am able to connect to the service. Issue is i want windows authentication. and i want to disable anonymous security. Soon as i disable anonymous and keep windows auth. i get an error: 
"the authentication schemes configured on the host ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.etc etc...."

When i turn anonymous back on with windows auth. Yes i can access the service but it doesn't use the windows auth.. its weird because other files such as test.html for example still require username/password. i don't know how to properly restrict a webservice for windows auth using ssl... can anyone help me?? please

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>


<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>


      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
 <services>
     <service name="WcfConcur.ConcurService">
        <endpoint address=""
               binding="wsHttpBinding"
               bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
               contract="WcfConcur.IConcurService"/>

<endpoint address="mex"
               binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>


<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>


      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

on the client side, i add a reference to the wcf. and it downloads this automatically.  thing is my intial wcf address that is hosted is https://address/whatever.svc  and when it downloads it shows http://internal address  i don't know if thats the issue

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <configuration>
          <startup>
                <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"    sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
            </startup>
             <system.serviceModel>
                  <client>
                  <endpoint address="http://internal address/wcfConcurService/ConcurService.svc"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IConcurService"
             contract="wcfConcurRef.IConcurService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IConcurService" />
            </client>
               <bindings>
                  <basicHttpBinding>
                     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IConcurService" />
                </basicHttpBinding>
                  </bindings>

           </system.serviceModel>
        </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message thrown, when anonymous access is disabled, seems to indicate an issue with the client configuration.

The client configuration appears to be using the `basicHttpBinding` which is different from the server configuration which is using `wsHttpBinding`.  To resolve the binding issue, you should copy the server binding configuration to the client configuration file and then update the client endpoint to use the new binding configuration.

Your client configuration should look something like:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://enter-external-address-here/wcfConcurService/ConcurService.svc"
               binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity"
               contract="wcfConcurRef.IConcurService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IConcurService" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: i'm also getting a There was no endpoint listening at that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.. for some reason the address on the client config has http:// internal address and not the external address. how can i fix that

Comment: Perhaps you could include the relevant sections of the client config file for review.

Comment: updated answer ... seems like you need to align the client / server bindings and then put in the proper external IP address and port

Comment: i see... i still get an error that its not listening at the endpoint after changing the client

Comment: even if i change the client, it still doesn't recognize that the service is listening. because when refresh the service, it always shows the "internal" address. and if i overwrite that again, it still doesn't want to work

Comment: If you can browse to the service (https://address/whatever.svc) from a web browser, then you know the service is listening.  Just put that address in the client endpoint configuration ... if that doesn't work, enable tracing to  further determine the issue ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: ok i got it to work actually, the service name was incorrect that is why it wasn't finding the correct link in the client... thanks..
i now have it secured with windows auth and https.  not sure if you know this but, do you know how to limit the windows auth to just a few people within your domain. i put authorization to just a few , but anyone in the domain with creds can login and i want to restrict that.. i tried but didn't work